# com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: ����(

Tags: android, serialization, kryo, snappydb

I am currently encountering the following exception:

```
eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9e878060, error=EGL_SUCCESS
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: ����(
Serialization trace:
badQuality (de.myproject.data.transform.MyPendingUpload)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:138)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:115)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:641)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:99)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:657)
    at com.snappydb.internal.DBImpl.get(DBImpl.java:249)
    at de.myproject.data.storage.SnappyKeyValueDatabase.get(SnappyKeyValueDatabase.java:39)
    at de.myproject.data.transform.MyServiceImpl$1$3.call(MyServiceImpl.java:230)
    at de.myproject.data.transform.MyServiceImpl$1$3.call(MyServiceImpl.java:224)
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162)
    at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7710)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:231)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:140)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:55)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.pollQueue(OperatorObserveOn.java:208)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:170)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Invalid name: ����(
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:136)
    ... 28 more
```

I am trying to build an offline mode for an Android App by storing data on the device using SnappyDB.

So when the user has no active internet connection, data is stored and when internet connection is available, the data should be read and uploaded to the server.

The PendingUpload class looks like this:

```
public final class PendingUpload implements Serializable {

    final SomeModel someModel;

    final Map<String, Image> images = new HashMap<>();

    Quality goodQuality;

    Quality badQuality;

    Image someImage;

    String string1;

    String string2;

    String string3;

    List<Pair<SomeClass, AnotherClass>> someList;

    List<Attachment> attachments;

    public MyPendingUpload(SomeModel someModel) {
        this.someModel = someModel;
    }

    protected MyPendingUpload() {
        someModel = null;
    }
}
```

And my Snappy Database looks like this:

```
public class SnappyKeyValueDatabase implements KeyValueDatabase {
    public static final String KEY_PREFIX = "snappyKeyValueDatabase_";
    @NonNull
    private final DB db;

    public SnappyKeyValueDatabase(@NonNull DB db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public void put(String key, Object object) throws IOException {
        try {
            db.put(KEY_PREFIX + key, object);
        } catch (SnappydbException e) {
            XLog.x(e);
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
        try {
            return (T) db.get(KEY_PREFIX + key, (Class<Serializable>) clazz);
        } catch (SnappydbException e) {
            XLog.x(e);
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(String key) throws IOException {
        try {
            db.del(KEY_PREFIX + key);
        } catch (SnappydbException e) {
            XLog.x(e);
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<String> list() throws IOException {
        try {
            String[] keys = db.findKeys(KEY_PREFIX);

            ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>(keys.length);
            for (String key : keys) {
                resultList.add(key.substring(KEY_PREFIX.length()));
            }

            return resultList;
        } catch (SnappydbException e) {
            XLog.x(e);
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

If you need any more information, please let me know.
I am stuck at this problem for a while now and appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you find a solution for this?